# Make extension optional in htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, option-type

I've got the following code in .htaccess: -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.pdf)$ showpdf.pdf?product_code=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

which takes a request in the format (for example): -

```
/ab-cde-123/anything-can-go-here.pdf
```

and rewrites it to: -

```
/showpdf.pdf?product_code=ab-cde-123
```

And this works fine. However, I want to change it slightly so that everything after the last / in the request is optional, for example so that all 3 of these would work as requests: -

```
/ab-cde-123/anything-can-go-here.pdf
/ab-cde-123/anything-can-go-here
/ab-cde-123/
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove the match for it, except you need to add a condition to keep it from looping:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/showpdf\.pdf
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? showpdf.pdf?product_code=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```